# Undefined variable: attens (View: D:\attendance\resources\views\empatten\show.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show all the rows from a table based on condition by choosing a date, Can anybody modify the below code. I tried to first list all the rows using the below code, but receving an error. I tried changing few things under the controller, but i couldn't manipulate the data. Any idea will be useful, I am beginner.

```
show.blade.php

<html>
<head>
<title>Display attendance information</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #104E8B; 
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" name="doa">
<input type="submit" value="Click here to View the attendance status" name="disp">

<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead>

<tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Emp Name</th>
<th>Emp Status</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>
foreach($empatten as $attens)
{
 <tr>
     <td>{{ $attens->empid }}</td>
 <td>{{ $attens->empname }}</td>
 <td>{{ $attens->empstatus }}</td>
 <td>{{ $attens->doa }}</td>

</tr>
}
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>

Mycontroller code:

return View('empatten.show')
     ->with('empatten', empatten::all());
```

Comment: you need to provide more code sample information. Like the controller from where the data `$empatten`  is sending and the data pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In blade, the loop should be like this:

```
 @foreach($empatten as $attens)
 <tr>
     <td>{{ $attens->empid }}</td>
     <td>{{ $attens->empname }}</td>
     <td>{{ $attens->empstatus }}</td>
     <td>{{ $attens->doa }}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```